# cURL Passing Parameters - PHP - Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, http, curl

I am using this cURL function to send a set of data that has to be received by the api. However the api receives null.

```
public static function httpPost($url,$type,$params)
{
    $postData = '';

    foreach ($params as $k => $v) {
        $postData .= $k . '=' . $v . '&';
    }
    $postData = rtrim($postData, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```

I have tried outputting the data before sending and it shows correct data. The other curl part works. Any idea why data is not being sent through curl?

Comment: does the API expect post or get?

Comment: It expects a get

Comment: use postman to test your url,check is it right?

Comment: then why are you using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` ?

Comment: Yes..that was the error.  I was using POST attributes. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not need to use POST, unset that curl option and use PHP [http_builder](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to build the URL

```
public static function httpPost($url,$type,$params)
{
    // Clean URL + append "?" at the end of URL + append the query
    $url = rtrim($url,"?") . "?" . http_build_query($params);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $type);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;

}
```